# Looking for a hint on this rolling the dice combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

You roll a dice 6 times in a row, and after each time you write down the number on the dice. This will form a 6-digit number.

Mariska throws two times a 4 and four times a 5. How many different digits can she form?

---

I really have no idea where to start.. Can someone give me a **hint**?

Comment: Hint: Permutation with identical objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If she had thrown one $4$ and five $5$s, she could have made $6$ different numbers, one for each of the $6$ positions in which she could put the $4$: $455555$, $545555$, $554555$, $555455$, $555545$, and $555554$.

How many different pairs of positions are there in which she can put the two $4$s that she actually did throw? Once you know where they are, you know the whole number, because every other position will have a $5$.